# how to set up the searchable fields in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, rank

I have incoming queries and I want to only search in certains fields (author, book title) not in field (book content). How can I achieve this in Lucene?

another questions is that if how can I give a higher rank to documents that have matches in the author field. For example, doc1 have match in "book content", and doc2 has match in "author", how can I rank higher for doc2

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple queries using BooleanQuery, and have Occur.Should (meaning OR). I also believe that you can boost specific queries in such a scenario, which means that matches in a specific field has higher relevance that for instance, content.

Example (C#):

```
var query = new BooleanQuery();
query.Add(new TermQuery("author", searchTerm), Occur.Should);
query.Add(new TermQuery("book title", searchTerm), OCcur.Should);
```